# How do I write this darned SQL query?

Tags: sql, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-3.1

I'm a relative sql notice, eager to learn, but I need some help putting together a query. If anyone can steer me in the right direction, I'd be grateful.

The table is TeamRankings. The columns are as follows:

```
score | qualities_id | team_id | year | source
```

Teams are scored with respect to different qualities for specific years. Note that a given team can can be assigned multiple scores (each one would be from a different source). Likewise, a given team might not have any scores at all for given year.

Here's the problem:

Given a single quality, and a list of teams, I want to find a list of years for which EACH of those teams has at least one score.

I'm coming at this from Rails (3.1), and I could do this a dumb way with Active Record and multiple db calls. But I'd like to be able to do in pure SQL. Bonus points for help in Active Record that limits to one db call.

Thanks much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an example for the case where you'd have 6 teams. The value you test in the HAVING clause (6 in my example), should match the number of team_ids included in the IN clause.

```
SELECT year
    FROM TeamRankings
    WHERE qualities_id = 1
        AND team_id IN (4,8,15,16,23,42)
    GROUP BY year
    HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT team_id) = 6;
```

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure how you pass in the parameter via Ruby, but here is some SQL. You may want to join in the Teams table to get the team name too. Not included in your schema, but ...

```
Select Distinct tr.Team_id, t.TeamName, tr.Year
From TeamRankings tr
  Inner Join Teams t
Where Exists (
  Select 1 From TeamRankings 
  Where Team_id=tr.TeamID and Year=tr.Year and qualityID=@qualityid
  )
```

Answer (score 1):

Using SQL only, you need to group the data be yar, and then use a HAVING clause to check that every team is present...

```
SELECT
  year
FROM
  TeamRankings
WHERE
  team_id IN (<your_list>)
  AND qualities_id = <your quality id>
GROUP BY
  year
HAVING
  COUNT(DISTINCT team_id) = <your number of teams>
```

The interesting bit is how to pass a list to a SQL Query.  My usual habit is to pass a comma delimited string of id', then have a sql function split that string out into a record-set.  It certainly doesn't feel elegant, but I've encountered much more, ummm, novel solutions...

```
SELECT
  year
FROM
  TeamRankings
INNER JOIN
  dbo.my_split_function(@list_of_ids) AS Team
    ON Team.id = TeamRankings.team_id
WHERE
  qualities_id = @quality_id
GROUP BY
  year
HAVING
  COUNT(DISTINCT team_id) = (SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT id) FROM dbo.my_split_function(@list_of_ids))
```